# Content-Encoding response header not returned in karate GET call

Tags: karate

Actually I was trying to migrate my  old test suite to Karate framework.
And I have to validate response headers, In that "Content-Encoding" header is not returned in Karate GET call - I checked it in results I could see all other response headers but not "Content-Encoding" and returns null for assertion.

The same GET call I checked it in chrome browser - developer console and POSTMAN in both the tools I could get "Content-Encoding" but not in Karate.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server returns `Content-Encoding` you will see it else you will not.

To validate that a header does *NOT* exist, it is simple:

```
And match responseHeaders contains { 'Content-Encoding': '#notpresent' }
```

Refer `responseHeaders`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#responseheaders

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it does not provide all response headers, because some, like "Content-Encoding: gzip" are stripped away by underlying Apache http libraries after decompressing the content it seems.

See:
[Having trouble getting content-encoding to show up in response header for get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61683562/having-trouble-getting-content-encoding-to-show-up-in-response-header-for-get-re)